# keep returning value error even though I change the s value

Tags: python, numpy, random

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

x = np.random.randint(-100,100,1000)
y = np.random.randint(-100,100,1000)
size = np.random.rand(100) * 100

mask1 = abs(x) > 50
mask2 = abs(y) > 50

x = x[mask1+mask2]
y = y[mask1+mask2]


plt.scatter(x, y, s=size, c=x, cmap='jet', alpha=0.7)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()



ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [56], in <cell line: 16>()
     12 x = x[mask1+mask2]
     13 y = y[mask1+mask2]
---> 16 plt.scatter(x, y, s=size, c=x, cmap='jet', alpha=0.7)
     17 plt.colorbar()
     18 plt.show()
ValueError: s must be a scalar, or float array-like with the same size as x and y
```

I can't find what's wrong with this code. It just returns a ValueError.  I am assuming something is wrong with the 'size = ' part. I tried changing size = np.random.rand(100) to (1000) but still didn't work.

Comment: Please include the error trace and message (as text) in the question.

Comment: Note that initially, x and y are of length 1000, and size is of length 100. That doesn't combine. Read the error message. Print out the lengths of x, y and s before calling plt.scatter

Comment: Thank you for all the comments by reading the comments I figured that the len(x) and len(y) was different after the mask therefore I had to add the mask to size too so that the len of x,y,size would all be the same! after I did size[mask1+mask2] the code worked as I intended.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies within `s=size`.  Either `s` has to be a single value for all your data points or there has to be a value for every data point. But `x.shape` and `y.shape` will be random. So in order to give every point a different size:

```
x = np.random.randint(-100,100,1000)
y = np.random.randint(-100,100,1000)

mask1 = abs(x) > 50
mask2 = abs(y) > 50

x = x[mask1+mask2]
y = y[mask1+mask2]

size = np.random.rand(x.shape[0]) * 100  # choose size depending on the number of data points x

plt.scatter(x, y, s=size, c=x, cmap='jet', alpha=0.7)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I tested it and it works fine, and hopefully as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation of scatter, size attribute should be a scalar or float array-like with the same size as x and y. After you modified your x and y variables, size variable shape doesn't match with x or y. That's why it's throwing value error.